# Access Macro Creating a Duplicate Table that then Breaks the Macro

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access

I inherited an Access based dashboard which uses a series of SQL queries and Make Table actions to write the results of those queries into tables located in two other Access files.

There is a macro that runs all of the make table commands which in turn run the sql queries.  All of them are working when I run this on my machine, but when I run it from our VM which handles scheduled refreshes, it creates a duplicate table for one of the queries.

If I delete that table from the Tables1 database, the Queries database will run successfully and create both the correct table, and the duplicate in Tables1.  However, each subsequent time, the macro will fail with an error saying that the duplicate table already exists.

This is the make table sql:

```
SELECT [SQLQueryName].* 
INTO [TableName] 
IN 'filepath\Tables1.accdb'
FROM SQLQueryName;
```

This is the same structure that all the other make table queries are using and they are not having this issue.  I'm not sure if this matters or will tell someone something, but the duplicate table is the same name with a 1 added to the end of it.  We also recently had to get a new VM setup and there have been a lot of weird issues with things not working as they did in the previous VM where this had been running without issue for quite a long time.

So far I've tried compacting both the Query and Table1 Database files.  I've tried deleting the make table query and making a new version.  I've tried deleting the table and duplicate from Tables1.  I've tried rolling back the database files to versions several weeks old.  We also made sure that the version of Access is the same as on my PC.

I am currently attempting to change it to a delete row/append row method rather than a make table, but even if that works I would still love to know why this is happening.

**Edit:**

Actual Code from make table that is failing, removed filepath.

```
SELECT [012_HHtoERorOBS].* 
INTO [HHtoER-Obs] 
IN '\\filepath\MiscTablesB.accdb'
FROM 012_HHtoERorOBS;
```

Here is code from 2 other make table queries that are working.  Each make table query follows an identical format of select * from the sql query to get the data into the table in the destination accdbs.

```
SELECT [010_ScheduledVisitsQuery].* 
INTO ScheduledVisits 
IN '\\filepath\MiscTablesB.accdb'
FROM 010_ScheduledVisitsQuery;

SELECT [020_HH_HO].* 
INTO HH_Referred_to_HO 
IN '\\filepath\MiscTablesB.accdb'
FROM 020_HH_HO;
```

All of these tables exist in the destination accdbs when the make table queries are run.  The macro does not include any commands to delete tables.  Here is a screenshot of the top of the macro, it repeats all the make table queries then ends with a command to quit access.

[image: Macro Screenshot]

Comment: It probably can't delete the old (existing) table, thus can't create the new.

Comment: Definitely a possibility.  Is there any way to tell why it can't delete this particular table, but can with the other tables?

Comment: We simply need more specific information to help. Please edit with actual SQL queries (even if repetitive) of all or sample of all your make-table statements. Are you using stored queries? VBA function? Actual or closer to actual names preferred over generic `TableName`.  Do each query use `IN` clause to external accdbs? All make-table queries should fail if their destination table exists.

Comment: Added additional info.  Those are the actual make table queries with filepath removed.  I don't think I'm using stored queries or VBA functions.  Every make table uses the same format with the in clause to destination access db.  None of the make table queries fail except for this one and they all have existing tables in the destination file.